# How to maintain mutiindex view in pandas while converting pandas dataframe to csv file?

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I have pandas dataframe where mutiindex is there(pic 1) but when i am converting it csv it not showing as multiindex(pic 2)

I am using to_csv() .Is there any parameter i need to pass to get right format?

pic 1:
[image]

pic:2

[image]

Tried as per suggestion, below is the pic

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're not bothered about getting a CSV as output the way I do this is by putting the data in an XLSX file.

```
# Create the workbook to save the data within
workbook = pd.ExcelWriter(xlsx_filename, engine='xlsxwriter')

# Create sheets in excel for data
df.to_excel(workbook, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# save the changes
workbook.save()
```

Can you try this and see if it formats how you want?

Comment: Thanks for the response but i am not getting the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be helpful for you:

```
    pd.DataFrame(df.columns.tolist()).T.to_csv("dataframe.csv", mode="w", header=False, index=False)

    df.to_csv("dataframe.csv", mode="a", header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Its not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using an older version of `pandas`. If you are using `<0.21.0`, there is a `tupleize_cols` parameter you can play with. If above, just save as `to_csv`. It will default to each index in one row -

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your rsponse, i tried but still in csv i am not seeing multiindex format. I have added the pic in the question itself